# Should I use AI on these fields in MySQL?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, database, indexing

I have this db below. I wonder how I should use the ID to identify each record.
Everything is connected from the `classified_table`!
Two Questions:

Should I use AI on every PK in this case?

Could somebody give me the FULL code for selecting an entire classified from only an `ad_id` ("bmw_330ci_8939483" for example)?

I am new to normalized db and making a good database work, so detailed instructions is very much appreciated... Also if you notice any 'wrongs' in this db please let me know.

```
category table:
cat_id (PK)
cat_name

category_options table:
option_id (PK)
cat_id (FK)
option_name

option_values table:
value_id (PK)
option_id (FK)
value

classifieds table:
classified_id (PK)
ad_id (VARCHAR) something like "Bmw330ci_28238239832" which will appear in URL
poster_id (FK)
cat_id (FK)
area_id (FK)
headline
description
price
etc....

posters table:
poster_id (PK)
name 
email
tel
password

area table:
area_id (PK)
area
community
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by AI in this context?

Comment: Allen Iversion or Artificial Intelligence?  I'm guessing auto increment in this context.

Comment: I was thinking of Haley Joel Osment: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0212720/

Comment: Ahh and PK is primary key, now I get it. @OP, please R from using A like that, not E gets them ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would auto-increment (AI) on fields that I would do majority of searching by. AI makes it easier to return results, but there are performance issues where it can slow down the database.

In regards to the query, I am not exactly sure what you would want to return, but this query returns the `classified_id` by the given `ad_id`

```
SELECT classified_id FROM classifieds_table WHERE ad_id = "bmw_330ci_8939483"
```

To perform a single insert into your *classifieds table* and column *ad id* the value *audi a4* would be:

```
INSERT INTO classifieds_table ad_id VALUES "audi_a4"
```

Or multiple inserts using the same table, multiple fields and multiple values would be:

```
INSERT INTO classifieds_table (ad_id, poster_id) VALUES ("audi_a4", 10)
```

Notice I left out `classified_id` because if you choose to auto-increment it will automatically assign a value without you explicitly assigning one.

Check out [**MySQL :: Building a Database-Driven Website using PHP and MySQL**](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/ddws/index.html) for more tutorials.

Comment: okay, thanks! Could you also answer this: How should I insert an ad into these tables? Multiple ""insert into statement?

Comment: What do you mean by ad? If you gave me more detail I could help

Comment: sorry, I mean a classified (my website is a classifieds website). For example, user fills in a form to insert a classified. Then I have problem with actually inserting it into the tables. I don't know where to start really... Do you understand? Thanks

Comment: I tried to demonstrate the basics of inserting above, hope this helps.

Comment: okay, I understand, but does this mean I have to make a new insert for every table right? and then do one mysql_query() for every insert statement right? Thanks again!

Comment: You cannot perform inserts onto multiple tables in one query. I would suggest starting off to perform one insert per one query just to get a feel for inserting and then when you feel ready enough, you can expand your skills.

Comment: If you need to do a set of inserts in one go into separate tables, a stored procedure would be a convenient way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Using auto-increment for your PKs sounds sensible, because it sounds like you already want to use a surrogate key and auto-increment makes the inserts very straightforward. Worth taking a look at this discussion about [how to pragmatically choose what primary key to use](http://database-programmer.blogspot.com/2008/01/database-skills-sane-approach-to.html).